# remove .each from jquery selector in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have coffee script below, to do remote ajax select2, this will set all class select2-autocomplete, the problem is I would like to put this script to just one item that just added, how I modify this script below without iterating each,

```
    $('.select2-autocomplete').each (i, e) ->
    select = $(e)
    options = 
      multiple: false
      width: "98%"
      placeholder: "Type Hotel name"
      minimumInputLength: 3
    options.ajax =
      url: select.data('source')
      dataType: 'json'
      type: "GET"
      quietMillis: 150
      # input untuk program
      data: (term) ->
        q: term
      results: (data) ->
        results: $.map(data, (item) ->
          text: item.name
          id: item.id
        )
    options.dropdownCssClass = 'bigdrop'
    select.select2 options
```

below is my HTML code, note: since I'm using select2 v.3.5.3 ajax I'm using hidden field (rails)

```
        <%= f.hidden_field :hotel_id, data: { source: search_name_hotels_path }, class: "select2-autocomplete", :value => "#{f.object.hotel_id unless f.object.new_record? || f.object.hotel_id.nil? }" %>
```

Comment: Please share you html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a small jQuery plugin that gets executed on element when called.

```
$.fn.enableAutocomplete = () ->
    select = this
    options = 
      multiple: false
      width: "98%"
      placeholder: "Type Hotel name"
      minimumInputLength: 3
    options.ajax =
      url: select.data('source')
      dataType: 'json'
      type: "GET"
      quietMillis: 150
      # input untuk program
      data: (term) ->
        q: term
      results: (data) ->
        results: $.map(data, (item) ->
          text: item.name
          id: item.id
        )
    options.dropdownCssClass = 'bigdrop'
    select.select2 options
```

And call this on element on which you want it to be enabled. Like below

```
$('#selectElement').enableAutocomplete();
```

Comment: Thank you, your comment above helped me solve my problem although not directly attached to.